# Why Cannot assign Google DNS adress to Android VPN service only local DNS server?

Tags: java, android, vpn, google-cloud-dns

-In this method i am trying to add google dns server to vpn interface but it doesnt work at all.It
work only local dns which is default dns server of gsm.
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
localAddress = CommonMethods.ipStringToInt(ipAddress);

```
    packet = new byte[20000];
    ipHeader = new IPHeader(packet, 0);
    tcpHeader = new TCPHeader(packet, 20);
    udpHeader = new UDPHeader(packet, 20);
    dnsBuffer = ((ByteBuffer) ByteBuffer.wrap(packet).position(28)).slice();

    proxy = new Proxy(this, 0);
    proxy.start();
    dnsProxy = new DnsProxy(this);
    dnsProxy.start();

    vpnThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            mInterface = builder.setSession("VPNtoSocket")
                    .addAddress(ipAddress,32)
                    .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
                    .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8");
                    //.addRoute("194.163.43.216", 32)
                    .establish();

            FileInputStream vpnin = new FileInputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
            vpnout = new FileOutputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());

            onStatusChanged(true);

            try{
                int size = 0;
                while(size != -1 && !vpnThread.isInterrupted()){
                    while((size = vpnin.read(packet)) > 0 && !vpnThread.isInterrupted()){
                        if(dnsProxy.isInterrupted() || proxy.isInterrupted()){ //KILL SWITCH
                            vpnin.close();
                            throw new Exception("Server stopped.");
                        }
                        onIPPacketReceived(ipHeader, size);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try{
                    vpnin.close();
                    vpnout.close();
                    if(mInterface != null){
                        mInterface.close();
                        mInterface = null;
                    }

                    kill();
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        }

    }, "VPNtoSocket");
    vpnThread.start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);//START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer, I know, but I've recently come across this issue.
Leaving this answer for anyone who sees this later.

So, for some reason, Android does not always resolve DNS according to the DNS server of the network that is "Active".
This happened to me in 2 scenarios:

- Wi-fi network but without internet - Android just ignores this network and tries to resolve DNS using the default DNS resolver instead of using the Wi-fi  provided DNS server. This is an issue because I have an endpoint in the router that has a hostname that can only be resolved using the router's DNS.
- VPN - Android still uses the default DNS resolver, even though all traffic should be captured by the VPN, it seems to do it outside of the VPN. In my case, my VPN was a local VPN and the device does not have any sort of internet connection (wi-fi or cell) but instead forwards the traffic to other device that has internet.

The oddest thing about this is that in this VPN scenario I had inconsistent behaviors accross different Android devices and versions. Some use the correct VPN DNS server and some use the default Android DNS resolver..

**Long story short**: The only way that worked for me to fix this and make sure that the DNS resolver from the VPN (or other network) is used instead of the default, is to bind the process to the network, in this case, the VPN network.

Here's how you can do it, before starting the VPN:

```
val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)
val request = builder.build()
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, object : NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            Log.i(TAG,"Binding to VPN Network!")
            val bindResult = connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
            Log.i(TAG,"Bind to VPN result = $bindResult")
        }
    })
```

If the code above does not trigger the callback when you start the VPN, you can also get the network object from the activeNetwork:

```
val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    

if (activeNetwork != null) {
        val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)
        val isVpn = networkCapabilities?.hasTransport(
            NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN
        ) ?: false
        if (isVpn) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Binding to VPN Network!")
            val bindResult = connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(activeNetwork)
            Log.i(TAG,"Bind to VPN result = $bindResult")
        }
    }
```

One last thing to consider is that this call to `bindProcessToNetwork()` doesn't always succeed (again, no clue why), so it's always better to implement some retry mechanism, for example retry 3 times with a delay of 3 seconds on each attempt. It's unclear what is the reason that this binding has failed and Google should have already added some more verbose return value that could indicate at least some more specific error code..